# Привязываю файл авторизации к главной странице, сайт не загружается, прошу подсказки

Tags: php

Вот файл `head.php` к которому привязываю файл..

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['check_user_attempt']))
    header('Location: .');

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] :  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

include('techworks.php');

$fk_merchant_id = '22256'; //merchant_id ID мазагина в free-kassa.ru http://free-kassa.ru/merchant/cabinet/help/
$fk_merchant_key = 'dzog8pvi'; //Секретное слово http://free-kassa.ru/merchant/cabinet/profile/tech.php

if (isset($_GET['prepare_once'])) {
    $hash = md5($fk_merchant_id.":".$_GET['oa'].":".$fk_merchant_key.":".$_GET['l']);
    echo '<hash>'.$hash.'</hash>';
    exit;
}

require(openid/openauth.php'); 


include_once('config.php');

if(isset($_GET['ref'])) {
    $_SESSION['ref'] = (int)$_GET['ref'];

    header("Location: ./?r=".$_SESSION['ref']);
}

if(isset($_SESSION["token"])) {
    $result = $link->query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `token`="'.$_SESSION["token"].'"');
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="interkassa-verification" content="5b5c52f78fe1fbad07b32f3c48b511fa" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flotr2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <script src="js/socket.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/case.js?<?=time();?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my.js?<?=time();?>"></script>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
  <title>c0unter-strike.top- Испытай удачу!</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Испытайте удачу при покупке случайных предметов для CS:GO. Открываем кейсы дешевле чем в Steam и выгоднее!">
  <meta name="keywords" content="case4fun, case, opening, рулетка, открытие, кейсов, cs, csgo, магазин, магазин случайных вещей, рандом, random, рандом кс, кейсы, кейс, открытие кейса, открываем кейс, case opening, cs-lottery">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?<?=time();?>">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=BebasBook:300">

</head>

<body>



    <!-- Payment Activator -->
    <div class="out_bg2 hidden"></div>
    <div class="pWindow hidden">
    <form method="POST" id="payform" action="process.php">
                            <input type="hidden" name="openid" value="<?echo $_SESSION["openid"];?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="<?echo time();?>">
        <div>      <h2 class="popup-title">Номер пополнения +79126977578 и указываем ник</h2>


        <div class="inner">
                <table style="margin: 30px 0px 30px 61px;display: block;float: left;">
              <tbody>
            <tr>
                  <td><input pattern="^\d+(\.\d*)?$" class="form-price form-text required pricefield-processed" type="text" id="edit-amount" name="sum" value="0" size="10" maxlength="128"></td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>

            <a href="#" class="cd-popup-close close-popup">×</a>

            <div class="btn-row">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn_red btn_pay add_fund">Пополнить</a>
            </div>

          </div>

    </div>
                            </form>
    </div>

<header class="header">
    <div class="content" style="width: 594px;">
        <a href="./" style="display: block;margin-left: calc(50% - 64px);width: 110px;"><img src="img/logo.png" style="position: relative;width: 97px;top: 9px;margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;">

        <ul class="menutop">
            <li><a href="index.php"><img src="img/ome.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php"><img src="img/Gg.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://vk.com/c0nterst" target="_blank"><img src="img/vk.png"></a></li>
            <?if(isset($_SESSION['openid'])) {?> 
                <li><a href="profile.php"><img src="img/myinv.png"></a></li>
            <? } else { ?>
                <li><a href="logger.php?login"><img src="img/steamlogin.png"></a></li>
            <? } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

</header>

<div class="content">
```

файл который пытаюсь прикрепить `openauth.php` (авторизация варгейминг):

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define('URL','http://gekeri6r.beget.tech/openid/openauth.php');//адрес по которому доступен данный скрипт
define('APPLICATION_ID','15fc5a2a344650620ee046b8df279a21');//application_id приложения
if(empty($_GET['status'])){//генерируем ссылку и перенаправяем пользователя
    $context = stream_context_create(
        array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => http_build_query(
                    array(
                        'nofollow' => 1,
                        'expires_at' => 300,
                        'redirect_uri' => URL,
                        'application_id' => APPLICATION_ID
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $data=json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://api.worldoftanks.ru/wot/auth/login/', false, $context),true);
    if($data['status']=='ok'){
        header ('Location: '.$data['data']['location']);
        exit();
    }else{
        exit('Не удалось получить ссылку для перенаправления.');
    }
}elseif(isset($_GET['status']) && isset($_GET['access_token']) && isset($_GET['nickname']) && isset($_GET['account_id']) && isset($_GET['expires_at'])){//если пользователь попал на страницу с параметрами, которые устанавливает метод auth/login
    if($_GET['status']!="ok"){
        $error_code=500;
        if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/u', $_GET['code'])){
            $error_code=$_GET['code'];

        }
        exit("Ошибка авторизации. Код ошибки: $error_code");
    }elseif($_GET['expires_at']<time()){
        exit("Ошибка авторизации. Срок действия access_token истек.");
    }else{
        $context = stream_context_create(
            array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => http_build_query(
                        array(
                            'expires_at' => 14*24*60*60,
                            'access_token' => $_GET['access_token'],
                            'application_id' => APPLICATION_ID
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        $data=json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://api.worldoftanks.ru/wot/auth/prolongate/', false, $context),true);//подтверждаем правдивость полученных параметров
        if($data['status']=="ok"){


$mas = $_GET;
$id = $_GET['account_id'];
$token = $_GET['access_token'];



//Выводим весь массив GET


   $_SESSION['token'] = $token; 


                include_once("set.php");
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE openid='".$id."'");
                if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
                    if(isset($_SESSION['ref'])) {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (token, referal) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['token']."',".$_SESSION['ref'].")") or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
                    } else {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (token) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['token']."')") or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
                    }

                    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
                    $id = mysql_num_rows($query2);

                    if($id % 100 == 0) {
                        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET bonus=(bonus+1) WHERE token='".$_SESSION["token"]."'");
                        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=(money+50) WHERE token='".$_SESSION["token"]."'");
                    }
                }


                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET nickname='".$_GET['nickname']."', token='".$token."' WHERE openid='".$id."'");
                $user = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE $id='".$id."'");
                $user = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
                if(isset($_SESSION['ref']) && $user['referal'] == "" && (int)$user['id'] != (int)$_SESSION['ref']) {
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".(int)$_SESSION['ref']);
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET referal='".$id."' WHERE $id='".$id."'");
                    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=(money+10) WHERE $id='".$id."'");
                }           



        }else{
            exit('access_token не подтвержден');
        }
    }
}else{
    $error_code=500;
    if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/u', $_GET['code'])){
        $error_code=$_GET['code'];
    }
    exit("Произошла ошибка. Код ошибки: $error_code");
}
?>
```

как только вписую файл `require(openid/openauth.php');` так главная страница не хочет загружаться... 
если поможет старый файл авторизации был steam, он работал ..

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require ('openid.php');

function logoutbutton() {
    //echo "<form action=\"steamauth/logout.php\" method=\"post\"><input value=\"Logout\" type=\"submit\" /></form>"; //logout button
    echo "<a href=\"steamauth/logout.php\" class=\"button7\">Logout</a>";
}

function steamlogin()
{
try {
    require("settings.php");
    $openid = new LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);

    $button['small'] = "small";
    $button['large_no'] = "large_noborder";
    $button['large'] = "large_border";
    $button = $button[$steamauth['buttonstyle']];

    if(!$openid->mode) {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
            $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
    //echo "<form action=\"?login\" method=\"post\" style=\"display: inline;\"> <input style=\"display: inline;\" type=\"image\" src=\"http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_".$button.".png\"></form>";
        //echo "<a href=\"?login\" class=\"login-link\"></a>";?>
        <?php
    }

     elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {
        if($openid->validate()) { 
                $id = $openid->identity;
                $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);
                var_dump($steamauth['loginpage']);
                //session_start();
                $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1]; 
                include_once("set.php");
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."'");
                if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
                    if(isset($_SESSION['ref'])) {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (steamid, referal) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['steamid']."',".$_SESSION['ref'].")") or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
                    } else {
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (steamid) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['steamid']."')") or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
                    }

                    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
                    $id = mysql_num_rows($query2);

                    if($id % 100 == 0) {
                        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET bonus=(bonus+1) WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION["steamid"]."'");
                        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=(money+50) WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION["steamid"]."'");
                    }
                }
                include_once("userInfo.php");

                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET nickname='".$steamprofile['personaname']."', avatar='".$steamprofile['avatarfull']."' WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION["steamid"]."'");
                $user = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."'");
                $user = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
                if(isset($_SESSION['ref']) && $user['referal'] == "" && (int)$user['id'] != (int)$_SESSION['ref']) {
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".(int)$_SESSION['ref']);
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET referal='".$row['steamid']."' WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."'");
                    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=(money+10) WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."'");
                }
                 if (isset($steamauth['loginpage'])) {
                    header('Location: '.$steamauth['loginpage']);
                 }
        } else {
                echo "User is not logged in.\n";
        }

    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Вижу редиректы я, циклические (с) Йода

Comment: Если у вас включен Хdebug и настроена связка с IDE, поставьте точку останова в начале скрипта, который подключаете и пройдитесь по скрипту. Вы сразу увидите в каком месте ошибка.

Comment: @alexkad извините, я слабенький очень , все что я вижу это ошибку mysql в том что это старая версия и больше не используется при запросе файла авторизации ,...

Comment: @Naumov можно поподробнее? пожалуйста